# Angular 9 + CLI (TypeScript) - How to stop generating .spec.ts test files

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-cli, angular2-cli

**I know it's kind of a bad practice**, but bear with me:

I'm using Angular-CLI, particularly `ng g` to generate all of my classes. However, I'm not interested in any `*.spec.ts` test files. I know that there are two flags (`--inline-template`, `--inline-style`) to handle inline CSS and HTML instead of separated files, and for spec the `--spec` flag is set to true by default.

So for each run, yes, I could do `ng g c foo --it --is --spec=false`.

But how do I disable the creation of test files globally? Is there any default setting for it?

Rashly, I did some stuff **(that didn't work)**, like:

```
ng set spec=false --global
```

I also tried configuring my `src/tsconfig.json` by filling the exclude array:

```
"exclude": [
    "**/*.spec.ts"
]
```

Answer (score 161, accepted):

### For Angular 9+ (version 6+ below)

*1) Copy snippet to the root of `angular.json`, (configures settings to all projects/globally).* 
*2) Or copy snippet to the root of a specific project (`projects.your-project-name`) in `angular.json` (configures settings for a specific project).*

```
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "style": "scss",
    "skipTests": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:class": {
    "skipTests": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:directive": {
    "skipTests": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
    "skipTests": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:service": {
    "skipTests": true
  }
},
```

**All configurable options per type of file [Schematic Options](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/tree/master/packages/angular/cli/lib/config):**

```
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "changeDetection": "Default",
    "entryComponent": false,
    "export": false,
    "flat": false,
    "inlineStyle": false,
    "inlineTemplate": false,
    "module": "",
    "prefix": "",
    "selector": "",
    "skipImport": false,
    "spec": true,
    "style": "css",
    "viewEncapsulation": "Emulated",
    "skipTests": "false"
  },
  "@schematics/angular:module": {
    "commonModule": true,
    "flat": false,
    "module": "",
    "routing": false,
    "routingScope": "Child"
  },
  "@schematics/angular:service": {
    "flat": true,
    "skipTests": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
    "export": false,
    "flat": true,
    "module": "",
    "skipImport": false,
    "skipTests": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:directive": {
    "export": false,
    "flat": true,
    "module": "",
    "prefix": "app",
    "selector": "",
    "skipImport": false,
    "skipTests": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:class": {
    "skipTests": true
  }
},
```

### For Angular 6+

*1) Copy snippet to the root of `angular.json`, (configures settings to all projects/globally).* 
*2) Or copy snippet to the root of a specific project (`projects.your-project-name`) in `angular.json` (configures settings for a specific project).*

```
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "styleext": "scss",
    "spec": false
  },
  "@schematics/angular:class": {
    "spec": false
  },
  "@schematics/angular:directive": {
    "spec": false
  },
  "@schematics/angular:guard": {
    "spec": false
  },
  "@schematics/angular:module": {
    "spec": false
  },
  "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
    "spec": false
  },
  "@schematics/angular:service": {
    "spec": false
  }
},
```

**All configurable options per type of file ([Schematic Options](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v6.0.0-rc.8/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L71)):**

```
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
    "changeDetection": "Default",
    "export": false,
    "flat": false,
    "inlineStyle": false,
    "inlineTemplate": false,
    "module": "",
    "prefix": "",
    "selector": "",
    "skipImport": false,
    "spec": true,
    "styleext": "css",
    "viewEncapsulation": "Emulated"
  },
  "@schematics/angular:module": {
    "commonModule": true,
    "flat": false,
    "module": "",
    "routing": false,
    "routingScope": "Child",
    "spec": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:service": {
    "flat": true,
    "spec": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
    "export": false,
    "flat": true,
    "module": "",
    "skipImport": false,
    "spec": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:directive": {
    "export": false,
    "flat": true,
    "module": "",
    "prefix": "app",
    "selector": "",
    "skipImport": false,
    "spec": true
  },
  "@schematics/angular:class": {
    "spec": true
  }
},
```

---

### Angular CLI configuration with Angular CLI

**ERROR:**

The `ng set defaults.spec.component false` command results in the error: `get/set have been deprecated in favor of the config command.`

`ng set` got changed to `ng config`.

**Using the Angular CLI (config command usage):**

The settings for generating specs, inline templates, inline styling etc. within `angular.json` are now persisted inside the `schematics.@schematics/angular.<file-type>.<setting>`.

Run `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.spec false` to configure spec for components. This command adds the setting inside the schematics property within the `angular.json` file.

---

[Angular CLI workspace file (angular.json) on Angular Github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/wiki/angular-workspace#angular-cli-workspace-file-angularjson-schema)

[Schematic options inside schema.json](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/v6.0.0-rc.8/packages/%40angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json#L71)

[How to do X in Angular CLI v6](https://medium.com/@beeman/how-to-do-x-in-angular-cli-v6-db7530c23066)

Answer (score 29):

If you're using v6 and need to edit your angular.json

You can edit the schematics for your project.

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "styleext": "scss",
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:class": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:guard": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:module": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:pipe": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "@schematics/angular:service": {
      "spec": false
    }
  },
```

Comment: it should be the correct answer with Angular 6. Add this code to angular.json file of the project. you should use VScode tool with "Angular Files" plugin to create service, component, module, routing...

Comment: Thanks.. it works for angular 7 too. Added at the end of angular.json file

Answer (score 24):

You can run this command to disable spec file generation for a specific type of file:

`ng set defaults.spec.FILETYPE false`

For example:

`ng set defaults.spec.component false // Won't generate spec files for .component files`

Alternately you can just disable all spec file generation from the angular-cli.json file.

```
{
  ...
  "defaults": {
    "spec": {
      "class": false,
      "component": false,
      "directive": false,
      "module": false,
      "pipe": false,
      "service": false
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `angular-cli.json` was deprecated in favor of `angular.json`. And there's no `defaults` key in angular.json so I'm afraid this answer is outdated.

Answer (score 15):

## For Angular 9+:

The `Angular.json` config has changed slightly which is causing previous configuration schemas to change, per this [GitHub issue on Angular/CLI](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16857).

Adapted from [@sacgrover's comment](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16857#issuecomment-583563378) along with [my own:](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/16857#issuecomment-584287851)

Old way

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {
    // true => DO generate spec files, false => DON'T generate them
    "spec": true,
    "styleext": "scss"
}
```

New way:

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {
    // true => DON'T generate spec files, false => DO generate them
    "skipTests": true,
    "style": "scss"
}
```

Additional Reference => [Angular Docs for CLI Generate Command](https://angular.io/cli/generate#component-command)

Comment: Property "@schematics/angular:component" is not allowed(angular10).

Answer (score 13):

Just to update [Sabbir Rahman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42049997/1575353):

In version 1.0.2 of the CLI you will have to set the spec file to *false* for each individual type. An example is included below:

```
"defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "service": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "directive": {
      "spec": false
    },
    "class": {
      "spec": false // Set to false by default
    },
    "module": {
      "spec": false // Set to false by default
    },
    "pipe": {
      "spec": false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 12):

you can add `--skipTests=true|false` if true it wont generate any *spec.ts*

example : `ng g component componentName --skipTests=true`

this line wont generate any *spec.ts* files

**EDIT:**

Note: As of angular 7 this command doesn't work, even though this command is mentioned on the official website of angular. 
Here: https://angular.io/cli/generate#component

Comment: didn't want to -1 your answer, but it doesn't work (I tried it with ng7)...

Comment: Tried with angular 9 and this worked. I prefer this way instead of disabling all spec files through json.

Answer (score 11):

you can add `--spec=false`

example

```
ng g c home --spec=false
```

log will be

```
CREATE src/app/home/home.component.scss (0 bytes)
CREATE src/app/home/home.component.html (23 bytes)
CREATE src/app/home/home.component.ts (262 bytes)
UPDATE src/app/app.module.ts (467 bytes)
```

Answer (score 9):

For angular 8+:

Option "spec" is deprecated: Use "skipTests" instead, so if you want to create a new component use:

```
ng g c my-new-component --skipTests=true
```

Comment: this is deprecated !!

Answer (score 7):

```
"@schematics/angular:component": {"style": "scss","skipTests": true}
```

Just add `"skipTests":true` to your **angular.json** file and you'll solve the problem

Answer (score 4):

you can try `--skip-tests` when you creating your app like below.

`ng new yourProjectName --skip-tests`

Answer (score 3):

Just do this and you should be fine:

```
ng generate component newFile --skip-tests
```

Answer (score 2):

you can add `--skipTests=true` to stop generating spec file

Example:

```
ng g s core/services/auth/auth-guard --skipTests=true
```

log will be

```
CREATE src/app/core/services/auth/auth-guard.service.ts (138 bytes)
```

Answer (score 1):

Add Following code on Angular.json

```
"schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular": {
      "component": {
        "spec": false
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Just Run this command: `ng config schematics.@schematics/angular.component.spec false`