# ng g class CLI command doesnt generate spec file

Tags: angular, angular-cli

So I want to generate an Injectable class with specific type (`my-store.store.ts`), but this:

`ng g class my-store --type=store`

Doesn't generate `spec` file and also doesnt add `@Injectable` decorator.

I am not using `ng g service` command, because [docs](https://angular.io/cli/generate#library) does not provide a `--type` option for it.

I can add `@Injectable` by hand, but would like to get spec file automatically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `--spec` flag so your command should be

```
ng g class my-store --type=store --spec=true
```

Comment: It works, but you explain how you came up with this? [docs](https://angular.io/cli/generate#class) does not provide `--spec` option for `ng g class`. there is only `--skipTests` which is by default false. Maybe its because my local CLI verson is 6?

Comment: --spec option is listed on doc page but mark as depricated   for angular 6+ you need to add schematics  https://stackoverflow.com/a/51096430/5621827

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `--spec` flag, as shown in the anwer by @jitender. Or you can check your `angular.json` file, for the `schematics` property.

[image]